# "I'd like to find a time to meet" en Español

Tags: traducción

I'd like to say that "I'd like to find a time to meet" in spanish to a spanish coworker, but I'm unsure how I would translate this concept.  I think it would be something like:

> quería **to find some time** pudiese reunirse con mi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, one note:

> reunirse **conmigo**

I think I would go with

> ¿Podemos acordar una fecha y hora para reunirnos?

or

> ¿Cuándo podría reunirse conmigo?

I think Spanish speakers wouldn't be too formal when trying to arrange a meeting (but as usual, it would depend on you relationship with those coworkers, their positions, or who else is CCed in that email). Please, don't hesitate to write again if you think we can help polishing that email.